# Using kubectl to wait until a pvc is bound

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I wanna use `kubectl wait` command to wait until a pvc is bound.

I tried `kubectl wait --for=condition=bound pvc/my-pvc-claim --timeout=2s` with a pvc which is already bound, but it doesn't seem to work. This is the output `error: timed out waiting for the condition on persistentvolumeclaims/my-pvc-claim`.

I read `kubectl wait` documentation, but still can't understand which condition I should use. How can I accomplish that? Is there a more complete documentation explaining how to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following command:

```
while [[ $(kubectl get pvc myclaim -o 'jsonpath={..status.phase}') != "Bound" ]]; do echo "waiting for PVC status" && sleep 1; done
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the jsonpath provided in subudears answer as the for option.
So this way you can utilise `kubectl wait`

```bash
kubectl wait --for=jsonpath='{.status.phase}'=Bound pvc/my-pvc
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try using explain to see what conditions are possible to make sure you have the right one. [Check here for an example of how you might use that.](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/66439#issuecomment-477242654)

Comment: Thanks, this link is helpful. I ran `kubectl explain pvc.status.conditions`, but in the output I see only this about type `type <string> -required-`

Comment: did you figure this out?

Comment: I did what is suggested in the accepted answer.